is there a way to be able to tell if an InDesign file is a template after it being sent to you?
So, I had a file sent to me and i think it might be a template. Is there a way to tell through InDesign if it is a template or not??

No. An InDesign file is an InDesign file regardless if it started as a template or not.

The original question was "is there a way to be able to tell if an InDesign file is a template". Seems like you are not at all interested in how to detect if a work has been built on a template. So, you got directly an answer based on that observation. The answer:
If you are asked to do a design from scratch and not to use a template - maybe for copyright reasons or to see what you actually know and can create by yourself - do as asked! If you use a template someone may find the template by making image searches or by asking AI or by being the creator of the template. A real guru or someone who knows the right people may dig up what's hidden into the Indesign file.
There's available no data in the manual of what data is NOT included. In theory it could contain a pretty good review of the history of the file; for example:

when created, in which individual computer, in which computer user account, in which software version licensed to whom, list of material pasted from other sources, used filename, where saved to
all the same for every edit session


I don't think the OP is trying to evade detection. However, your bulleted points do offer a way to try and deduce that. indesign does have metadata for images, date of creation, and placement etc. It is not particularly useful, but it is in the file menu under "file info." image placement date(s) are visible in the links pallette
